# Get pointer() object (or address) of Structure's field

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes, ioctl

I am trying to build a binding in Python using ctypes.

I want to call ioctl from my Python project.

First of all, here is a similar structure to what I use.

```
class struct_some_struct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("field1",  c_uint32),
                ("field2",  POINTER(c_uint8)]
```

Suppose we have declared something like:

```
mystruct = struct_some_struct()
```

Here is the deal.
I am currently using addressof(). It succeeds on most situations but when the address is greater than INT_MAX, (which occurs very often on 64 bit machines), I am having problems, getting OverFlowErrors, e.t.c. So I am thinking of rewriting it using pointer(), instead of addressof().

I need to get the address of field1 because ioctl needs a pointer to this specific field.
This field is filled by a previous ioctl call passing a pointer to mystruct (No problems on that ioctl).

With addressof() a solution could be:

```
addressof(mystruct) + struct_some_struct.field1.offset
```

And this would be the address of field1.

But as I mentioned I don't want to use addressof().

How can I pass a pointer() (pointer to field1) object to ioctl()?

Typing:

```
pointer(mystruct.field1)
```

wont work because type(mystruct.field1) is not c_uint32, but int according to Python.

Also doing something like:

```
pointer(c_uint32(mystruct.field1))
```

is not good either because ioctl may change field1, and by doing this changes won't affect mystrcuct.field1 value.

I could use byref(mystruct, struct_some_struct.field1.offset), but fcntl.ioctl does not accept it (libc's ioctl accepts it though)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you declared `fcntl.ioctl` with `ctypes`?  `byref(struct,offset)` is the correct way to pass the pointer to `field1`, but if that doesn't work the problem is likely in the declaration of `ioctl` I don't see here.

Comment: I did something like:
    import fcntl,
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, OP, byref(struct, offset)
and i get
TypeError: an integer is required
But if instead using fcntl's ioctl, do the following:
    from ctypes import CDLL,
    libc = CDLL("libc.so.6"),
    libc.ioctl(fd, OP, byref(struct, offset))
It works!!!!

I prefer to use the fcntl's ioctl.... but I can't

Comment: That makes sense.  `byref` returns a `ctypes` object called `cparam 'P'`, which is a `ctypes` type that only a `ctypes`-based function is going to know what to do with.  It looks like you should use `byref` with a `ctypes`-wrapped `ioctl`, and `addressof` + offset is the solution for `fcntl.ioctl`, but without a real, working example of the error it's hard to tell.